# how to manage PHP session in android using HttpClient?

Tags: java, php, android, cookies, httpclient

I'm building a php API that needs the client to be signed on to return some information.. the code for this page is as follows:`

```
include('connect.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    # select data from the database and echo it back.
}
else {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    echo -1;
}
?>
```

but before this the customer should login using another page `

```
if (isset($_GET['usr']) && isset($_GET['password'])){
    $usr = $_GET['usr'];
    $passwd = $_GET['password'];

    $login = 0;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from users where userName=? and passwd =?");
    $stmt->execute(array($usr,$passwd));
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $login = 1;
            session_start();
            $id = session_id();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $usr;
            break;
    }

    if($login == 1) {       
        echo "signed on";
    }

    if($login == 0) {
        echo "username or password incorrect";
    }
}
else {
    echo "parameter not set";
}

?>
```

when I try this from the browser it works very well. but when I tried this from the android app it didn't seem to work, I set the PHPSESSID Cookie using setHeader for the metho, also I tried the method from the answer here [How to Handle the Session in HttpClient 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272575/how-to-handle-the-session-in-httpclient-4-1) but it didn't work, I could sign in, and when printing the cookies in the CookieSotre I can see the PHPSESSID is set, but also the server can't consider me as logged in..
Here is my code 

**ClientUtils.java**

```
public class ClientUtils {

public static final DefaultHttpClient myHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
public static final HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
public static final CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();


public static void config() {
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
}

public static void printCookies() {
    for(Cookie k :cookieStore.getCookies())
        Log.d(k.getName(), k.getValue());
     }
}
```

**LoginTask.java**

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    try {
        ClientUtils.config();
        String urlll = "http://192.168.200.15/login.php?usr=monim&password=monim";
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlll);               
        HttpResponse response = ClientUtils.myHttpClient.execute(httpget, ClientUtils.httpContext); 
        ClientUtils.printCookies(); //this print the value of PHPSESSID
    }catch(Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String... url) {
    // do something 
}
}
```

**and for the second page I use this snippet of code**

```
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = ClientUtils.myHttpClient.execute(getRequest, ClientUtils.httpContext);
```

but this does not work I always get the wrong response, am I missing something? is there any other headers other than the sessionId I should use?
please help..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that much on HTTP Components, but there is a nice webpage which may help you: [HttpComponents Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/FrontPage)

Also, :

1. Instead of simply starting the PHP session, you should try getting the

```html
session_id()
```

in the first snippet.

2. Check if the cache of Java is activated. Try [Tag Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaia.html)
3. [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) to read cookies
4. And [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615789/how-to-share-session-between-php-app-and-java-ee-app) on "How to share session between php app and Java EE app?"

Good luck!!!